# Finding infinitely many cubics on $\Bbb{P}^2$ whose strict transforms are exceptional curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, blowup

Let $\Bbb{P}^2$ be the projective space over $\Bbb{C}$.

It is a well known fact that the blowup of $\epsilon:S\to\Bbb{P}^2$ at $9$ points $P_1,...,P_9$ in general position generates infinitely many exceptional curves, i.e. infinitely many smooth, irreducible curves $C\subset S$ of genus zero with $C^2=-1$.

The simplest examples are:

a) the exceptional divisors $E_i:=\epsilon^{-1}(P_i)$.

b) the strict transforms of the lines $P_iP_j$ with $i\neq j$.

c) the strict transforms of the conics $C_{i_1,...,i_5}$ passing through five points $P_{i_1},...P_{i_5}$ with $1\leq i_1<...<i_5\leq 9$.

I'm now interested in generating an infinite set of exceptional curves distinct from the ones above.

Here's my idea: let $\mathcal{C}$ be the set of cubics with multiplicity 2 in $P_1$, multiplicity 1 in $P_2,...,P_7$ and not passing through $P_8,P_9$. If $C\in\mathcal{C}$, then its strict transform $\widetilde{C}$ is smooth of genus zero with $\widetilde{C}^2=C^2-2^2-6\cdot 1^2=9-10=-1$.

I'm trying to show that $\#\mathcal{C}=\infty$. I think it is possible to argue that the cubics with an order 2 singularity at $P_1$ and smooth at $P_2,...,P_7$ form a pencil $\mathcal{P}$ and there are only finitely many cubics in $\mathcal{P}$ passing through either $P_8$ or $P_9$.

I'm having difficulty to formalize the argument for the dimension of $\mathcal{P}$. How do I prove that the multiplicity 2 at $P_1$ makes the dimension drop by two?

(if I'm talking nonsense, please let me know)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, a rational $(-1)$-curve $C$ on a surface $S$ never deforms. In particular, it is not a member of a movable linear systems. This follows from the exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_S \to \mathcal{O}_S(C) \to \mathcal{O}_C(-1) \to 0
$$
which shows that
$$
h^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(C)) = h^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S) = 1.
$$
So, to get infinitely many curves you must find (or show the existence of) infinitely many appropriate divisor classes.

Comment: Oh, of course... in general, $C$ does not deform whenever $C^2<0$, right? I'm still trying to find where exactly my argument fails, though. I'm sure that the cubics passing through $P_1,...,P_7$ form a linear system with dimension $2$. By what you said, if we ask for multiplicity two at $P_1$, this should drop the dimension by $2$. How could that happen?

Comment: If you ask multiplicity 2 at $P$ it will drop the dimension by 3, because the value of the section and two its derivatives must vanish,